Faster matrix processing (in chunks?) for large matrices
I have two large matrices, each having 2 columns and too many rows:
DimMat1 <- 50000
DimMat2 <- 20000
X <- 1:10000000
set.seed(123)
s1 <- matrix(sample(X, DimMat1*2), ncol = 2)
set.seed(456)
s2 <- matrix(sample(X, DimMat2*2), ncol = 2)
set.seed(789)
Vect <- rnorm(DimMat1)
Denom <- 508000
rm(X)

dim(s1)
# [1] 50000     2
dim(s2)
# [1] 20000     2
length(Vect)
# [1] 50000

I want to implement the following code, which I copied from an R package. The following is a bottleneck for the function, taking too much time and ram to run. The challenge is that this has to be repeated too many times (20K), using different values for Vect and Deonom vectors.
Dist1 <- Rfast::Dist(s1)
dim(Dist1)
# [1] 50000     50000
Dist2 <- Rfast::dista(s1,s2)
dim(Dist1)
# [1] 50000     20000

# Each step is really time consuming, particularly the last
K11 = exp(-Dist1 / Denom)
K12 = exp(-Dist2 / Denom)
m = crossprod(K12, solve(K11, Vect))

Is it possible to execute the previous code in small chunks (i.e., time- and RAM-friendly) and get the same values as the original code? Is there another way to implement the same using other packages? I tried to use some C++ code for the calculation, but this did not improve memory/time. However, my experience with C++ is very limited.
I tried to convert the data into float32 using the float package, but this did not help much.

If s1 and s2 don't change on each iteration, you need to calculate the distances only once, right? So the thing that needs to be optimized is crossprod(K12, solve(K11, Vect)).

Yes. I tried to pre-calculate the distance only once, but the resulted distance matrices are around 10GB.  Division and exponentiation for the K11 and K22 also takes time.
I need to optimize the division by single vector and exponentiation of K11 and K22 before the last step of crossprod(K12, solve(K11, Vect))

If I was in your shoes before pushing further in this direction, I would want to confirm I don't have an x - y problem, and that there wouldnt be a better way to compute ( or approximate) what I wanted results for.

My experience on this is rather limited. I copied the previous chunk from an R package. I used profiling and found that this step was the bootleneck and I needed to speed it up.

but why are you using the r package, what are you trying to solve by this method? what does the information in your matrix represent ?

I haven't checked yet, but I think you can get away with performing a single QR decomposition for all values of Denom. That should speed it up immensely.

I am using the Hmsc R package to fit a model on the distribution of many species. This code is copied from the part of the package that predicts the spatial effect of an MCMC model. See original code

@jblood94 I do not know QR decomposition, but the challenge is that the values for Vect and Denom change in each of the 20K iterations. The only step that can be done once is the calculation of the distances. Thanks for trying to help.

Could you potentially downsample the data so that some observations can be grouped together? If you could replace a 50k x 50k matrix with a 5k x 5k matrix, there'd be 100x fewer calculations to do. Would the loss of precision be meaningful in your context?

@JonSpring I do not think this is possible. The 50K * 50K matrix represents the distance between all locations used to train the models. The other matrix represents the distances between training and new sites. I am not a developer of the (complex) package, but only need to speed it up.

@AhmedEl-Gabbas, nevermind. I don't think that kind of shortcut will work with Denom in the exponent of K11.
